# $|f(z)|\leq\sqrt{|z|}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}$ implies $f=const$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Analytic function in the punctured plane satisfying $|f(z)| \leq \sqrt{|z|} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260817/analytic-function-in-the-punctured-plane-satisfying-fz-leq-sqrtz-f)

Let $f$ be an holomorphic function in $\mathbb C-\{0\} $ so that $$|f(z)|\leq\sqrt{|z|}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}.$$

Prove that $f=\text{const}$.

I'd be happy for a hint.

Thanks.