# Show that if $f$ is analytic when $z \neq 0$ and $|f(z)| \leq \sqrt{|z|} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}} $ then $f$ is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

*Note: This is a problem from an introduction course in complex analysis for engineers.*

Problem: Show that if $f$ is analytic when $z \neq 0$ and $|f(z)| \leq \sqrt{|z|} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}} $ then $f$ is a constant.

Given: $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n z^n $ in the plane $ 0 < |z| < \infty$.

Attempt at solution: By the cauchy inequality theorem we have \begin{equation}C_n \leq  \frac{\sqrt{p} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}}{p^n} \end{equation}

where $p$ is the radius of the circle $|z| = p > 0$ in the complex plane and $n \in \mathbb{Z} $.

We want to show that $C_n = 0 $ for $n \geq 1 $ and $n \leq -1$, because this would mean $f = C_o = constant.$ 
We see that if $p \rightarrow \infty $  and $n \geq 1$ then 
\begin{equation}C_n \leq  \lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{p} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}}{p^n} = 0. \end{equation}

On the other hand, if $p \rightarrow \infty $  and $n \leq -1$ then

\begin{equation}C_n \leq  \lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{p} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}}{p^n} = \infty. \end{equation}

The first limit gives us $C_n = 0 $ for $n \geq 1$, great. The second limit doesn't give us what we want (namely $C_n = 0$.). I am stuck here trying to prove that $C_n = 0$ for $n \leq -1$. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to use [Riemann's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) (condition $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$, in this case $a=0$), to see that $f$ is actually analytic, and then to do the same with $g(w)=f(1/w)$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @user90189 We already know that f is analytic, that is given. What we are trying to show is that f must be constant. If that is what you mean, I am sorry if I might have misread your post.

Comment: Dear @Gustaf, you said $f$ is analytic in $z\neq 0$, but I mean $f$ is analytic for every $|z|<\infty$ by Riemann's theorem.

Comment: This is solved here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260817/analytic-function-in-the-punctured-plane-satisfying-fz-leq-sqrtz-f